# Did the Giant Trinity A1 come with a derailleur hanger?

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, build

I am putting a bike together and have it all apart but don't see the derailleur hanger anywhere.  Did I lose it or did the bike not come with it?  If it didn't come with it, why not?

Thanks.

Comment: If it came with a derailer one would expect it to come with the hanger.

Comment: (And how would you lose a hanger?  Are you assembling this in tall grass?)

Comment: What year is this frame?

Answer (score 2):

The rear derailleur hanger on the Trinity was not replaceable, it was part of the frame and was there at the time of production.

[image: 2007 Giant Trinity A1]

If there is no hanger on the end of the rear drop out then it has likely been either:

- purposely removed (to make a single speed or fixie, possibly for track racing);
- sheered off in a crash (or deformed and then removed); or
- not an authentic Trinity frame.

Comment: All the Giant road bikes I've seen have the hanger attached by 3 very small hex screws. From Google images, this looks no different

Comment: I'd think alex is probably right - you can find the hanger at your local giant dealer probably.

Comment: @Alex the Trinity was a TT bike not a road bike. It's also probable that someone would use it as a track bike as well so would remove the hanger.. Feel free to post an answer and vote mine down if you know otherwise.

Comment: @Batman assuming one was in fact available the best source of replacement hangers is wheels manufacturing, they machine replacement hangers for most big manufacturers. It is unlikely the a local dealer would hold a part for a 6 year old frame unless it was a mountain bike (which break and bend often).